How can I use SearchKit and FormBuilder to show a table of matching contacts under Contact Summary by comparing custom field values?
I would like to help users to find matching "Mentor" contacts for "Mentees" based on values held in custom data fields and providing a tab on the Contact Summary called "Matching Mentors".
The Mentees complete a drop down list field called "Mentee Area", which is part of a multi-value custom data group. They can submit multiple Mentor requests.
The Mentors complete a field called "Mentor Area" which uses the same values as the list above, but is a different custom field in a single value custom data group.
So I need to combine all the "Mentee Area" values a Mentee has submitted, then use these as a filter in the "Matching Mentors" searchkit, i.e. "Mentor Area" in "list,of,mentee,areas".
I've got as far as creating the searchkit and form, then exposing this under the contact summary, but I can't see how to pass the contextual filter of "Mentee Areas" to the searchkit.
Perhaps I can achieve this using the "filters" attribute of the form markup with a custom token?
Maybe we're pushing serckit and formbuilder too far and need to bite the bullet and create an extension?
I hope this makes sense. Any help or advice, much appreciated as always.

Adding an example may help folk including me picture what you are doing more quickly.

SearchKit works by using the underlying data about how tables connect to each other.  If that connection doesn't exist, SK can't join the tables.
I believe the underlying API supports joins on arbitrary fields, but I'm not 100%.  If so, you can modify the SearchKit query in the civicrm_saved_search table.
You haven't specified the type of custom field you're using - but I suspect it's an alphanumeric multiple-choice question.  Consider making a new entity "Mentoring Area", then use Entity Reference custom fields. While this normally requires an extension, it should be doable with the Entity Creation Kit extension.
Entity Reference fields automatically create joins between the custom field and the entity for SearchKit. So you would join from mentee to entity to mentor, or vice versa.

Thanks Jon, those are two really useful leads. We're trying to avoid complexity so will checkout the saved_search table and see if we can add the joins there. Thank you!
